# Why does using `(char *[])` instead of `(char [][7])` for an array work?

Tags: c, arrays, function, casting

What happens underneath the following two pieces of code?

```
/* Piece #1 : Prints Garbage Values. */
char *res_str(int n) {
    return (char [][7]){"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"}[n];
}

/* Piece #2: Prints Correct Values.*/
char *res_str(int n) {
    return (char *[]){"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"}[n];
}
```

- What is the difference between these two?
- Is it possible to use alignment or `__attribute__((packed))`? How?

I call the funcion using:

```
printf("%s", op_str(n));
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Sorry! :) Similar construct may be also possible in C++, thus...

Comment: printf("%s", op_str(n));

Comment: +1 - I don't think enough people really understand how array and pointers work in C. I like this question as an educational thing

Comment: Thank you! :) From my understanding it could be because of alignment or possibly because of sections in which the Strings are placed (BSS)... Still waiting for an answer...

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Seems like a good and legit question to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
(char [][7]){"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"}
```

creates a 2D array on the stack with the contents of the strings provided in the brace enclosed initializer list copied into the respective slots of the array.

This

```
return (char *[]){"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"}
```

creates an array of `char*`s (pointers to `char`) on the stack each pointing to the base address of the respective string literals.

---

Now here is the catch: **Arrays go out of scope when the execution goes out of the block the arrays are declared in**.

In the first example you've shown, the array is destroyed once the function ends. This means that when the execution reaches the `printf`, you **aren't** supposed to read / write into this memory location as it has now become invalid for you to tamper with.

In the second case you have some pointer to `char` pointing to the base address of the string literals. The thing here to note is that **String literals have static duration and exists as long as the program does**. This means that by the time the execution returns to the `printf`, you can still read the string literal as they aren't freed.

Note that I said "*You can still **read** the string literal*" in the above paragraph but not *write* into it. This is because **String literals are immutable** meaning that they cannot be changed. **Any attempt to alter the contents of a string literals will result in *Undefined Behavior***.

Comment: Good catch. I was going into the inititalization mechanism, but didnt find anything wrong. I guess this is the right answer. +

Comment: @W0lfstein to complete the experience and prove that the initialization did not go wrong, try to find a way to printf the same result before returning from the function. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same difference as if you used variables instead of obfuscation:

```
/* Piece #1 : Prints Garbage Values. */
char *res_str(int n) {
    char words[][7] = {"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"};
    return words[n];
}

/* Piece #2: Prints Correct Values.*/
char *res_str(int n) {
    char *words[] = {"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"};
    return words[n];
}
```

The first returns a pointer to the first element of a local array - the pointer that the array `words[n]` decays into - as opposed to a pointer to the memory where the literal is stored.
Since the array's lifetime ends when the function returns, the returned pointer becomes invalid at that point.
Using it is undefined.

I have no idea what you mean by your second question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the sub-arrays go out of scope and the function returns a pointer only. Had it been like this, it might have possibly worked :

```
typedef char array[7];
array res_str1(int n) {
    /* The Deobfusscation helps! :) */
    char words[][7] __attribute__((packed)) = {"Char", "Match", "Jmp", "Split", "None"};
    return words[n];
}
```

But C does not allow returning arrays, and hence this code would not even compile. 'Why does C not allow returning arrays' might be a separate question in itself. Also, for here, attribute(packed) is rejected by the compiler (redundant?), but attribute(aligned) works, why?
Again, if the array is made static, this code will work, as explained correctly.
Thank you all for the answers! :)